# sort processes by cpu usage in cygwin

Tags: process, cygwin, cpu-usage

I need to sort processes by cpu usage in cygwin.

I already tried `tasklist` but it shows only processes ordered by memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `top` command will display Cygwin processes by CPU usage.

If you'd like to view only Windows processes, you can use the `ps` command, and then sort your results by CPU usage:

```
ps -W | sort -nk 3
```

where:

```
-W refers to Windows processes,

-n refers to a numerical sort, and

-k refers to a key, in this case the 3rd column of output from ps.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to sort process as per cpu utilization:

```
ps axo %cpu,command | sort -nr
```

Comment: Note that the [Cygwin version of `ps`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ps.html) does not accept formatting options.